How can you explain the substantially lower trading volume shown in IBKR?
I am using IBKR API to download historical data. The trading volumes are always substantially lower than from Yahoo Finance and Nasdaq.com, often lower by 50%. It is impossible to be explained by regular trading hours. I see some other posts saying regular lot of 100 shares etc so should multiply by 100; I think that is already corrected and is irrelevant here. I am setting SMART as the exchange already and my data match those from running the sample codes so my codes are correct.
I do see on its doc that,

IB's historical data feed is filtered for some types of trades which generally occur away from the NBBO such as combos, block trades, and derivatives. For that reason the historical data volume will be lower than an unfiltered historical data feed.

But the difference is way too large. How is it possible for volumes to differ so massively? Does it have anything to do with darkpools etc?
For example:



Ticker
Date
Nasdaq/Yahoo
IBKR
%diff




AAPL
20240628
82,542,720
42,812,041
50%


AAPL
20240627
49,772,710
31,916,744
30%


AMD
20240628
56,204,620
41,151,992
30%


AMD
20240627
34,018,220
26,066,024
20%


TSLA
20240624
61,992,070
47,662,995
20%


META
20240626
8,882,337
4,309,977
50%


APP
20240625
4,042,492
2,085,910
50%


BOX
20240627
1,621,128
694,668
60%


BASE
20240628
2,320,411
612,166
70%


CAT
20240628
8,891,479
1,704,328
50%


OXY
20240624
10,315,120
6,688,195
30%


KO
20240627
8,494,123
4,918,846
40%



